# Promote build with Jenkins API

Tags: jenkins, build

Given a Jenkins build job with different promotion jobs (i.e., that promote builds to different environments), how can one trigger a specific promotion job for a specific build using the Jenkins API?

Answer (score 3):

Combined answers from different sources to come up with this:

```
$Username = "Username"
$APItoken = '12345'
$Credential = "$($Username):$($APItoken)"
$EncodedCredential = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($Credential))
$BasicAuthValue = "Basic $EncodedCredential"
$Headers = @{
                Authorization = $BasicAuthValue
            }

Write-Output "Promoting build $LatestBuildNumber to Environment..."

Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://jenkins.prd.company.com/job/jobname/buildnumber/promotion/forcePromotion?name=PromoteToEnvironment" -Headers $Headers
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but just to help the community.

Shell Solution using [CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
user_name="jenkins_user"
    user_token="token" 
    promotion_name="Test_Promote"
    jenkins_url="http://build-server.com"
    JOB_NAME="job_name"
    JOB_NO="job-no"

    url="--silent -u $user_name:$user_token $jenkins_url/job/$JOB_NAME/$JOB_NO/promotion/forcePromotion?name=$promotion_name"
    curl $url
```

How to generate jenkins user token: https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/new-api-token-system/