# Promoting a build in jenkins by the rest api

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way of promote a build via the Jenkins REST API ?

If there isn't such a way, is there any way of doing it by code (script, etc.) ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate for this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311953/promote-build-with-jenkins-api

Comment: Thanks for the answer oblio!
I tried everything that is out there but nothing seems to work.
This answer that you mantioned is for force promotion, I need the simple one.

Comment: What happens if you replace forcePromotion with promotion in the URL in that example?